# Что именно означает слово «запись» в сокращении «ЗАГС»?

Tags: значения

Это означает место где находятся «записи» (акты) или может действие, «записывание»?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Запись" здесь означает глагол, "записывание".

Сокращение произошло от названия, в котором было слово "Отдел": "Отдел записи актов гражданского состояния". Но аббревиатура ОЗАГС, хотя и используется, встречается реже (см.: http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?&text=%D0%9E%D0%97%D0%90%D0%93%D0%A1 )

Чаще "Отдел ЗАГС" или просто "ЗАГС".

Answer (score 1):

Второе. Слово `запись` в данном случае совпадает с `записывание`.